# How to display verbatim code in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm currently using `helpText` in my `ui.R` file to display some static code content. However, because the output is not fixed width, the code looks like a mess. So how to display verbatim code; fixed width so it's easy to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, but the first solution would be `renderVerbatim`. If that doesn't cut it, you could look at [ShinyAce](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyAce/), though that may be overkill for what you need; if does have nice features like syntax highlighting for R, though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is highly related to a related Shiny question about rendering multiple lines of text at once:

[Outputting multiple lines of text with renderText() in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233497/outputting-multiple-lines-of-text-with-rendertext-in-r-shiny)

At least, the main answer there is one way to solve this problem.