# Outputting multiple lines of text with renderText() in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to output multiple lines of text using one `renderText()` command. However, this does not seem possible. For example, from the [shiny tutorial](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/lessons/Lesson-4/) we have truncated code in `server.R`:

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    output$text1 <- renderText({paste("You have selected", input$var)
    output$text2 <- renderText({paste("You have chosen a range that goes from",
      input$range[1], "to", input$range[2])})
  }
)
```

and code in `ui.R`:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  mainPanel(textOutput("text1"),
            textOutput("text2"))
))
```

which essentially prints two lines:

```
You have selected example
You have chosen a range that goes from example range.
```

Is it possible to combine the two lines `output$text1` and `output$text2` into one block of code? My efforts so far have failed, e.g.

```
output$text = renderText({paste("You have selected ", input$var, "\n", "You have chosen a range that goes from", input$range[1], "to", input$range[2])})
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can use `renderUI` and `htmlOutput` instead of `renderText` and `textOutput`.

```
require(shiny)
runApp(list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("censusVis"),
  sidebarPanel(
    helpText("Create demographic maps with 
      information from the 2010 US Census."),
    selectInput("var", 
                label = "Choose a variable to display",
                choices = c("Percent White", "Percent Black",
                            "Percent Hispanic", "Percent Asian"),
                selected = "Percent White"),
    sliderInput("range", 
                label = "Range of interest:",
                min = 0, max = 100, value = c(0, 100))
  ),
  mainPanel(textOutput("text1"),
            textOutput("text2"),
            htmlOutput("text")
  )
),
server = function(input, output) {
  output$text1 <- renderText({paste("You have selected", input$var)})
  output$text2 <- renderText({paste("You have chosen a range that goes from",
                                    input$range[1], "to", input$range[2])})
  output$text <- renderUI({
    str1 <- paste("You have selected", input$var)
    str2 <- paste("You have chosen a range that goes from",
                  input$range[1], "to", input$range[2])
    HTML(paste(str1, str2, sep = '<br/>'))

  })
}
)
)
```

Note you need to use `<br/>` as a line break. Also the text you wish to display needs to be HTML escaped so use the `HTML` function.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose there is no way to do this without html code?

Comment: That `HTML()` wrap is clutch. At first glance I was worried this was a hack and the only available option... But actually most of the code in this answer is from the question's example. It is really simple to switch to `HTML()` inside `renderUI({})`, and then `htmlOutput()` on the `ui.R` side. Nice answer!

Comment: @Alex I guess you can also use verbatimTextOutput() instead of textOutput(), but you may not want the gray shading.

Comment: +1 nice answer. How would you format the text inside `HTML()`? For instance, `HTML("<b>paste(str1, str2, sep = '<br/>')<\b>")` does not work

Comment: I have created this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392784/bold-text-in-html-output-r-shiny) if you're interested in answering

Comment: For  htmlOutput("text") + output$text <- renderUI({...}) you can just do htmlOutput("text") + textOutput(paste(str1, str2, sep = '<br/>')). No need for the renderUI or HTML() wrap

Answer (score 12):

According to [Joe Cheng](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/8GmXV-UfTm4):

> Uhhh I don't recommend using `renderUI` and `htmlOutput` [in the way that is explained in the other answer]. You are taking text that is fundamentally text, and coercing to HTML without escaping (meaning if the text just happens to include a string that contains special HTML characters, it could be parsed incorrectly).
>
> How about this instead:

```
textOutput("foo"),
tags$style(type="text/css", "#foo {white-space: pre-wrap;}")
```

(Replace the foo in #foo with the ID of your textOutput)

Answer (score -3):

If you mean that you don't care for the line break:

```
output$text = renderText({
  paste("You have selected ", input$var, ". You have chosen a range that goes 
  from", input$range[1], "to", input$range[2], ".")
})
```