# how to insert new line in R shiny string

Tags: r, shiny

In shiny, I have the following:

```
  output$sequenceText <- renderText({
    showSequence()
  })

showSequence <- reactive({
  selectedSeqs <- as.numeric(input$sequenceSelect)
  resultString <- ""
  currentString <-""

  for(i in selectedSeqs){
    currentString <- paste(i, toString(myProts[i]), sep = ":")
    resultString <- paste(resultString, currentString, sep = "\n")
  }
  return(resultString)

})
```

However, it doesn't seem that the new line character is respected. How do I fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outputting multiple lines of text with renderText() in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233497/outputting-multiple-lines-of-text-with-rendertext-in-r-shiny)

Comment: `verbatimTextOutput()` and `renderText()` will respect `\n` characters.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are only two options to display multiple lines within shiny.  One way with using `verbatimTextOutput` which will provide a gray box around you text (personal preference).  The other is to use `renderUI` and `htmlOutput` to use raw html.  Here is a basic working example to demonstrate the results.

```
require(shiny)
runApp(
  list(
    ui = pageWithSidebar(
      headerPanel("multi-line test"),
      sidebarPanel(
        p("Demo Page.")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("text"),
        htmlOutput("text2")
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){

      output$text <- renderText({
        paste("hello", "world", sep="\n")
      })

      output$text2 <- renderUI({
        HTML(paste("hello", "world", sep="<br/>"))
      })

    }
  )
)
```

This yields the following figure:

[image]

Comment: assuming you already have some text somewhere in your app, e.g., a reactive expression, and it already contains the `\n` newline characters in it.  Use `htmlOutput("text3")` with `output$text3 <- renderText({ gsub(pattern = "\\n", replacement = "<br/>", yourtext) })`

Comment: I would use the code below of @Serhii because using HTML can disable other "htmltools" features you want to include, reported here ("You will not be able to use tag related functions. We strongly recommend using R as much as possible and avoid mixing HTML with R.")[https://unleash-shiny.rinterface.com/htmltools-overview.html]

Answer (score 21):

for anyone reading this, you might also want to use tags$br(), which you simply have to insert as argument after a piece of text. For example,

```
tags$div(
    "a piece of text", tags$br(),
    "this will start from the new line now", tags$br(),
    "and this as well",
    "but not this" )
```

Answer (score 19):

How about

```
  output$text2 <- renderUI({
    HTML('hello <br> world')
  })
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a different approach which is perhaps a bit simpler.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  htmlOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$text <- renderText({

    paste0("<p>", letters[1:10], "</p>")
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the `write(x, file = "")` trick:

```
renderPrint({
 write(showSequence(), file = "")
})
```

If the output is a `verbatimTextOutput` then this works.

Answer (score 0):

`br()` adds a break within or outside functions:

```
  p("example text", br(), "next line text")
```

which is the same as:

```
  p("example text"), 
  p("next line text")
```

[image]

OR `br()` outside of text functions will give an empty line break

```
  p("example text"), 
  br(),
  p("next line text with a gap in between")
```

[image]

you can add as many consecutive breaks as you want.