# R Shiny Dashboard Infobox over two lines

Tags: r, shiny

I want to have an infobox show text over two lines. For example, if I were to combine html and and shiny (like one does for the popups in leaflet):

```
output$myInfoBox <- renderInfoBox({infobox(paste("Output1: ", myout1, "<br>", "Output2: ", myout2, sep = ""))})
```

I've tried `"<br>", "\n"`, etc. Nothing works.

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this (possibly related) answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26368406/1167750) help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to insert new line in R shiny string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368192/how-to-insert-new-line-in-r-shiny-string)

Answer (score 13):

I was struggling with this as well. The solution I found is to use the shiny HTML() function which explicitly marks text as HTML to avoid escaping.

For example, if you execute `infoBox("test_id",paste("test_value",br()))` in the R console, you'll see that the break tag br() is escaped as `&lt;br/&gt;`. Thus, the solution is to specify that it is html.

```
infoBox("test_id",HTML(paste("test_value",br())))
```