# Multi-line text output in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that allows the user to specify a bunch of options for building a statistical model, and the end result is supposed to be the output of a series of regression coefficients, as shown in this screenshot of a simple `print()` to the console:

[image: correct output shown in the console]

However, when I try to render that exact message to my Shiny UI, newlines are ignored, resulting in a jumbled mess of characters, like this:

> unmarkedFrame Object 16 sites Maximum number of observations per site:
>   23 Mean number of observations per site: 4.38 Number of primary survey
>   periods: 23 Number of secondary survey periods: 1 Sites with at least
>   one detection: 16 Tabulation of y observations: 0 1 22 48 298
>   Site-level covariates: site Elevation Min. : 1.00 Min. : 148.2 1st
>   Qu.: 4.75 1st Qu.:1085.0 Median : 8.50 Median :1318.2 Mean : 8.50 Mean
>   :1604.8 3rd Qu.:12.25 3rd Qu.:2264.2 Max. :16.00 Max. :2958.9 NA's :4
>   Yearly-site-level covariates: Year 2016 :80 2013 :64 2014 :48 2015 :48
>   2017 :48 2012 :32 (Other):48 Year 2016 :80 2013 :64 2014 :48 2015 :48
>   2017 :48 2012 :32 (Other):48

So the question is:

## How can I get the text to output to my shiny webpage while maintaining the readable formatting of the console output?

I found the following related question, but neither answer seemed to solve my problem...

[how to insert new line in R shiny string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368192/how-to-insert-new-line-in-r-shiny-string)

Comment: Have you tried using `verbatimTextOutput` with `renderPrint` in server.R? That should give you a look like in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: I needed to use the `collapse` argument in `paste` such that `<br>` was inserted between *every* item in the character vector `capture.output(print(summary(m0)))`.

The next problem was that whitespace would be ignored (because HTML), which I fixed by sandwiching the output between `<pre>` tags in order to preserve whitespace verbatim. The solution in `server.R` looks like this:

```
output$modelParameters <- renderUI(
        HTML(
          paste(
            c("<pre>", capture.output(print(summary(m0))), "</pre>"),
            collapse = "<br>"
          )
        )
      )
```

When called in `ui.R` by `htmlOutput("modelParameters")`, it outputs the text, formatted appropriately in a grey box, as intended.