# How to do a line break in renderText() in Shiny

Tags: r, text, shiny

I want to have a line break inside a `renderText()`, but none of the ways I know work. This is a short, reproduceable (and dull) example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("textOut")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$textOut <- renderText({
    paste0("First line", "\nSecond Line", "<br>Third Line")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, this gave me:

```
First line Second Line<br>Third Line
```

I've tried `\n`, `\br`, `<br>`, `</br>`, `<\br`, `<br><\br>`, etc. I've even tried using `%>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)`, but nothing seems to work.

I want to avoid using `renderHTML()`, but if it's the *only* way, then that's fine. Also, I do not want to make multiple `renderText()`s – that really is a last-case scenario, because it's tedious, it consumes too many variable names and can't possibly be the optimal solution.

Comment: Instead of `textOutput` in your `ui` could you use `verbatimTextOutput` instead? Or anything from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368192/how-to-insert-new-line-in-r-shiny-string/26368406) helpful? Also suggests `renderUI` with `HTML`...

Comment: Yes, `verbatimTextOutput()` did it. Thanks!