# verbatimTextOutput() not displaying text

Tags: r, shiny

Example below. I would like to add a sentence to my app via the UI section. Not my call to `verbatimTextOutput("Some Text Here \n and a new line here")`:

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot"),
           verbatimTextOutput("Some Text Here \n and a new line here")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run this I see this:
[image]

Have been reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368192/how-to-insert-new-line-in-r-shiny-string) post since I want to be able to add new lines with `\n` within a string of text, but cannot seem to be able to display just text in the app.

How can I add "Some Text Here \n and a new line here" in my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the name indicates, `verbatimTextOutput` is for rendering an output. It is usually used with `renderPrint` in the Shiny server file. That is, in `server`:

```
output[["mytext"]] <- renderPrint({
  "Some Text Here \n and a new line here"
})
```

and in `ui`:

```
verbatimTextOutput("mytext")
```

But since you don't need a reactive text, you can simply use a `p` tag in `ui` (and nothing in `server`:

```
tags$p("Some Text Here \n and a new line here")
```

If the linebreak does not work (I have not tried), you can try:

```
tags$p("Some Text Here", br(), "and a new line here")
```

or

```
HTML("Some Text Here <br> and a new line here")
```