# Make bold text in HTML output R shiny

Tags: html, r, formatting, shiny

Reproducible example:

```
require(shiny)
runApp(list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Example"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("index", 
                label = "Select a number",
                min = 1,
                max = 4,
                step = 1,
                value = 2)),
  mainPanel(
  htmlOutput("text")
  )),
server = function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderUI({
    HTML(paste(c("banana","raccoon","duck","grapefruit")))
  })
}
))
```

I would like to have the word corresponding to index ("raccoon" in the default) displayed in **bold** and the other words in normal font.

If I do:

```
HTML(
<b>paste(c("banana","raccoon","duck","grapefruit")[input$index])<\b>,
paste(c("banana","raccoon","duck","grapefruit")[setdiff(1:4,input$index)])
)
```

I receive an error (`<` is not recognized)...

Comment: You could add a div in the ui.r like div( outputelement, style = 'font-weight: bold;')

Comment: the problem is that I need on the same line `character_vector[index]` in bold and `character_vector[setdiff(1:length(character_vector),index)]` in regular font

Answer (score 36, accepted):

One more try, is this helpful?

```
require(shiny)

fruits <- c("banana","raccoon","duck","grapefruit")

runApp(list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Example"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("index", 
                label = "Select a number",
                min = 1,
                max = 4,
                step = 1,
                value = 2)),
  mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("text")
  )),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$text <- renderUI({
      fruits[input$index] <- paste("<b>",fruits[input$index],"</b>")
      HTML(paste(fruits))
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! +1 for storing raccoon and duck in `fruits` :)

Answer (score 20):

This might help you:

```
shinyApp(
  ui <- basicPage(
    uiOutput(outputId = "text")

  ),
  server <- function(input,output){

    output$text <- renderText({
      HTML(paste0("<b>","bold","</b>", " not bold"))
    })

  })
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: thanks for trying to help me, but unfortunately, I'm not dealing with text but with an R object (inside paste). I'm trying to come up with a reproducible example, stay tuned

Comment: I've added a reproducible example

Answer (score 5):

If you're not set on using the `HTML` function, I believe you should be able to use `strong(paste(character_vector[index]))` instead.

Comment: inside a `renderText` statement?

Comment: @Antoine That was not specified in the original question, in addition, the comment provided by Sebastian is helpful, but then your additional comment adds more complexity -- perhaps you need to provide a full reproducible example so that others can help and handle the details of your problem. Just mock-up a simple example with some of the built-in data sets.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand your answer. Which function do you suggest using in lieu of the `HTML` function? You have to plug `strong(paste(character_vector[index]))` somewhere

Comment: I've added a reproducible example per your request

Answer (score 0):

Just use `renderPrint` instead of `renderText`

```
renderPrint({
HTML(paste0("El valor 1 es:", input$val1,"\n","el valor 2 es:",input$val2))
})
```