# Using renderUI in Shiny to display vectors

Tags: html, r, vector, shiny, render

I want to be able to display a dynamic vector as text output in my Shiny app. I also want to utilize HTML (bold, font colors, etc.), so I am using `htmlOutput` and `renderUI` instead of `textOutput`and `renderText` per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392784/make-bold-text-in-html-output-r-shiny).

Here is some example code:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(

  ui <- htmlOutput("example"), 

  server <- function(input, output, session){

    # vector (in the real app, this is not a static vector--it will be updated with other inputs)
    states <- c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas")

    # text output
    output$example <- renderUI({

      x <- paste0("<strong>Here are your states</strong>: ", states)
      HTML(x)

    }) #END RENDERUI
  } #END SERVER
) #END SHINYAPP
```

The result of this code is:

> **Here are your states:** Alabama Here are your states: Alaska **Here are**
>   **your states:** Arizona **Here are your states:** Arkansas

What I want is :

> **Here are your states:** Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas

I have come up with a solution using conditional statements, but it's pretty clunky. Here's what I put in `renderUI` for the above desired output:

```
x <- paste0("<strong>Here are your states: </strong>", 
            if(!is.na(states[1])){states[1]}, 
            if(!is.na(states[2])){states[2]},
            if(!is.na(states[3])){states[3]}, 
            if(!is.na(states[4])){states[4]})
HTML(x)
```

Again, the above solution works, but it's rather clunky and will be terribly inefficient for larger vectors (with, let's say, 10+ elements). Is there an easier way to display these vectors while still being able to utilize HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `paste(..., collapse = " ")`.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(

  ui <- htmlOutput("example"), 

  server <- function(input, output, session){

    # vector (in the real app, this is not a static vector--it will be updated with other inputs)
    states <- c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas")

    # text output
    output$example <- renderUI({

      x <- paste0("<strong>Here are your states</strong>: ", paste(states, collapse = " "))
      HTML(x)

    }) #END RENDERUI
  } #END SERVER
) #END SHINYAPP
```

Comment: Yes, this does the trick! It's amazing how many simple things get lost in the mix when you're self-taught. Thanks!