# format helpText in shinydashboard::box

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a helpText widget in a shinydashboard box in my shiny app.
A helpText outside a shinydashboard::box() can easily be formatted, however, in the box(), new lines as well as other HTML elements, are not respected.
please find below my code and the image I currently am getting.

```
validation_rules_text_cas<-helpText('Please enter one string per line.', # ----
                        "A CAS Registry Number includes up to 10 digits which are separated in 3 hyphens.",
                        '- The first part of the number, starting from the left, has 2 to 7 digits',
                        '- The second part has 2 digits',
                        '- The final part consists of a single check digit.')
validation_rules_text_inchikey<-helpText('Please enter one string per line.',
                                  "International Chemical Identifier KEY validation rules.  InChIKey consists of several distinct components:",
                                  "- 14 characters resulting from a hash of the connectivity information of the InChI,encodes molecular skeleton (connectivity),",
                                  "- followed by a hyphen,",
                                  "- followed by 8 characters resulting from a hash of the remaining layers of the InChI,",
                                  "- Encodes proton positions (tautomers), stereochemistry, isotopomers, reconnected layer,",
                                  "- followed by a single character indicating the kind of InChIKey,",
                                  "- followed by a single character indicating the version of InChI used,",
                                  "- another hyphen,",
                                  "- followed by single character indicating protonation.(Source: Wikipedia).",
                                  "  AAAAAAAAAAAAAA-BBBBBBBBCD-E")

tabPanel("Batch Search", #----
                        fluidRow(column(5),
                                 column(7,# helpText----
                                        box(title=' CAS Validation Rules',width=12,
                                            collapsible = TRUE,
                                            collapsed=TRUE,
                                            status = 'primary',
                                            validation_rules_text_cas
                                          ),
                                        box(title='Inchikey Validation Rules',width=12,
                                            collapsible = TRUE,
                                            collapsed=TRUE,
                                            status = 'primary',
                                            validation_rules_text_inchikey
                                        ),
                                        box(title='SMILES Validation Rules',width=12,
                                            collapsible = TRUE,
                                            collapsed=TRUE,
                                            status = 'primary',
                                            validation_rules_text_smiles
                                        ),
                                        box(title='Validation Rules - OTHER',width=12,
                                            collapsible = TRUE,
                                            collapsed=TRUE,
                                            status = 'primary',
                                            validation_rules_text_other
                                        ))
))
```

[image]

How do I add new lines breaks (tags$br()) or new lines (tags$hr())? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33394512/7600300), you can use `renderUI` in the server function, and `htmlOutput` in the ui.  So for example:

```
output$validrules <- uiOutput({ 

          HTML(paste(
          p('Please enter one string per line.'), 
          p("A CAS Registry Number includes up to 10 digits which are separated in 3 hyphens."),
          p('- The first part of the number, starting from the left, has 2 to 7 digits'),
          p('- The second part has 2 digits'),
          p('- The final part consists of a single check digit.')
          ))
    })
```

Then:

```
box(title=' CAS Validation Rules',width=12,
                             collapsible = TRUE,
                             collapsed=TRUE,
                             status = 'primary',
                             htmlOutput("validrules")
                         )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `\n` in `renderText` will do it.  Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style("#inchikey{color: blue;
                                   font-size: 16px;
                                   line-height: 0.6;
                                  }"
  )),

tabPanel("Batch Search", #----
         fluidRow(column(5),
                  column(7,# helpText----
                         box(title=' CAS Validation Rules',width=12,
                             collapsible = TRUE,
                             collapsed=TRUE,
                             status = 'primary',
                             validation_rules_text_cas
                         ),
                         box(title='Validation Rules - OTHER',width=12,
                             collapsible = TRUE,
                             collapsed=TRUE,
                             status = 'primary',
                             verbatimTextOutput("inchikey")
                             #validation_rules_text_inchikey
                         )
                         )
         ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$inchikey <- renderText({
    paste("Please enter one string per line.,   \n
  International Chemical Identifier KEY validation rules.  InChIKey consists of several distinct components: \n
  - 14 characters resulting from a hash of the connectivity information of the InChI,encodes molecular skeleton (connectivity), \n
  - followed by a hyphen, \n
  - followed by 8 characters resulting from a hash of the remaining layers of the InChI, \n
  - Encodes proton positions (tautomers), stereochemistry, isotopomers, reconnected layer, \n
  - followed by a single character indicating the kind of InChIKey, \n
  - followed by a single character indicating the version of InChI used, \n
  - another hyphen,  \n
  - followed by single character indicating protonation.(Source: Wikipedia). \n
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAA-BBBBBBBBCD-E", sep="\n")
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]