# Change line inside shiny::renderText() used in flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have the basic flexdashboard below. What I want is to change line after "hello" in order to place "world" below it,inside the `renderText()`. I have found that I can use `htmlOutput()` and `verbatimTextOutput()` but these are not used in `flexdashboard`.

````
---
title: "[School Name] Enrollment Projections for Fall 2019"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    runtime: shiny
---
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)

```
Column {.sidebar }
-------------------------------------
### Menu
```{r}
renderText({
      paste("hello", "world", sep="\n")
    })
```

Row {data-height=400}
-------------------------------------
### Enrollments
```{r}
```
````

Comment: You can switch to using `renderUI()` in**flexdashboard** much like what is shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23322262/2461552) to use HTML for formatting text outputs.