# R shiny : display text as code on several lines

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to display some R code on my shiny app. Therefore, I used `verbatimTextOutput` but I can't find a way to break lines and to display paragraphs of code.

This solution ([Outputting multiple lines of text with renderText() in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233497/outputting-multiple-lines-of-text-with-rendertext-in-r-shiny)) only works with the `HTML` function and there is no way (to my knowledge) to mix `verbatimTextOutput` and `htmlOutput`.

I can display code with `tags$code` but it is not the appearance I would like (I would prefer the grey background).

Here's a reproducible example :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(htmlOutput("base", placeholder = FALSE))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$base <- renderUI({
    tags$code(HTML(paste("just", "some", "code", sep = '<br/>')))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have previously used `cat()` for this purpose:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("vtout"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$vtout <- renderPrint({
    cat("just", "some", "code", sep = "\n")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to use ```renderPrint``` before