# How to display word from a sentence one after another in specific time interval in shiny web application?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am developing a shiny application to display words and images from an XML file one after another in the given time interval (let's say 1 second) on shiny UI. If a user selects a file, it read the file and display the 1st word on UI then after 1-second 1st word disappears and 2nd word displayed on UI and then again after 1-second 2nd word disappears and 3rd word displayed on UI and so on. If there is an image in the file then it should also display on UI and after 1 second it should also disappear.
I wrote a code to get a word from a sentence in each second of interval. Right now it is displayed on R console but I want to display these words and images in the shiny UI.
Below is an illustration of the problem (it's not my actual code for cleanliness reasons, but it works as an illustration):
Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tokenizers)
library(magick)
library(stringr)
library(qdap)
library(xml2)


ui <- dashboardPage(skin = 'purple',
                   dashboardHeader(title = "Document Reader"),
                   dashboardSidebar(width = 200,
                                    sidebarMenu(
                                      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))
                                    )
                   ),
                   dashboardBody(skin = 'purple',
                                 tabItems(
                                   # First tab content
                                   tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                                           h2("Dashboard tab content"),
                                           fluidRow(
                                             box(title = "Uploading File",
                                                 fileInput("file1", "Choose a Document:"),
                                                 actionButton(inputId = "submit",label = "Read")

                                             ),
                                             column(8,verbatimTextOutput("opt1"))
                                           )
                                   )
                                 )
                   )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

 dw <- eventReactive(input$submit,{
   filepath <- input$file1$datapath
   doc <- read_xml(filepath)
   nodeset <- xml_children(doc)
   for(i in 1:length(nodeset)){
     wpm <- as.integer(xml_attr(nodeset[i], "wpm"))
     #print(paste("WPM", wpm))
     data2 <-xml_find_all(nodeset[i], ".//p | .//localImage")
     line <-  xml_text(data2)
     image <-  xml_attr(data2, "descr")
     image <- image[!is.na(image)]

     for(j in line){
       #print(j)
       if ( j == ""){
         tiger =  image_read(image)
         sink(tempfile())
         print(tiger)
         sink()
       }
       else{
         words = unlist(strsplit(j, ' '))
         words = words[words !=""]
         words = str_remove_all(words, "\n")
         total = length(words)
         for (w in 1:total){
           len = length(words[[total]])
           for (w1 in 1:len){
             if (str_detect(words[[w]][w1],'[.]')){
               print(words[[w]][w1])
               Sys.sleep(1)
             } else {
               print(words[[w]][w1])
               Sys.sleep(0.5)
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 })
 output$opt1 <- renderUI({
   dw()
 })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <section wpm = "200">
         <p>History</p>
         <p>The society that sparked change at Cambridge</p>
         <p>The ancient university owes its scientific status to an unexpected source, finds Georgina Ferry.</p>
    <localImage id="0" caption = "The Cambridge Observatory was founded in 1823, four years after the Cambridge Philosophical Society" descr="/home/i9/DocumentReader/DocumentReader/image/Image1.png"/>
         <p>We conclude this section by discussing the problem of classification,since it will serve as a prototypical problem for a significant part of this book. It occurs frequently in practice: for instance, when performing spam filtering, we are interested in a yes/no answer as to whether an e-mail contains relevant information or not.</p>
    </section>
</data>
```

How can I display these words on shiny UI.

Comment: Hi, is my answer help you ?

Answer (score 0):

I find one solution thanks to google and mixing different sources :

```
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = 'purple',
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Document Reader"),
                    dashboardSidebar(width = 200,
                                     sidebarMenu(
                                       menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))
                                     )
                    ),
                    dashboardBody(skin = 'purple',
                                  tabItems(
                                    # First tab content
                                    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                                            h2("Dashboard tab content"),
                                            fluidRow(
                                              box(title = "Uploading File",
                                                  fileInput("text", "Enter Text:"),
                                                  actionButton(inputId = "submit",label = "Read"))

                                              ,box(verbatimTextOutput("var"),column(8,uiOutput("opt1"))
                                            ),

                                              box(actionButton(inputId = "display",label = "display")
                                              )
                                    )                              



                    ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(words = character(0), n = 0,
                       sentence = "")
  # action button 
    # output$var <- renderText({
    #   if(input$display < length(input_file1()))
    #     return(input_file1()[input$display])
    # })
    # 

   observe({
     if(input$submit){
       rv$sentence <- unlist(strsplit(readLines(input$text$datapath), ' '))
     }
    # Re-execute this reactive expression immediately after 
    # it finishes (though you can also specify a longer time:
    # e.g. 1000 means re-execute after 1000 milliseconds have
    # passed since it was last executed)
    invalidateLater(1000, session)
    isolate({
      if (rv$n >= length(rv$sentence)) {
        return()
      } else {
        rv$n <- rv$n + 1
        rv$words <- rv$sentence[rv$n]
      }
      })
    })
    output$var <- renderPrint({
       return(rv$words)
    })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To sum up :

1. You can't use both `reactiveEvent()` and `observe()`
2. You could use `invalidateLater` really useful to redo an observe()
3. You must change a bit of things to do it with xml but in theory it will work  hope

Source :

1. [R Shiny: reactiveValues vs reactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436713/r-shiny-reactivevalues-vs-reactive)
2. [Outputting multiple lines of text with renderText() in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233497/outputting-multiple-lines-of-text-with-rendertext-in-r-shiny)
3. https://gist.github.com/bborgesr/61409e3852feb991336757f06392e52a

Comment: I tried this but it is showing words on the progress bar but I want to show this word on the center of UI without progress bar.

Comment: @ Remi coulaud, I edited the above code, please look this.

Comment: Did you find an answer ?