# Shiny : import Rdata file

Tags: r, shiny, rdata

I want to import 2 Rdata files into my shinyapp, then display the tables in the mainpanel, I tried the following code but it gives me a character output:
[image]

What should i add to my code to have the dataframes ? how can I allow to my app to import also csv files ?

This is my code :

server.R :

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){
#lecture de la table panel
  panel <- reactive({
    req(input$pan)
    sessionEnvir <- sys.frame()
    if (!is.null(input$pan)) {
      p<-load(input$pan$datapath, sessionEnvir)

    }
 p
    
  })

  #lecture dela table achat
  achats<- reactive({
    req(input$achat)
    sessionEnvir <- sys.frame()
    if (!is.null(input$achat)){
      a<-load(input$achat$datapath, sessionEnvir)
    }
    a

  })
 
  
 
output$t <- renderTable(
  panel()
  )
output$t2 <- renderTable(
  achats()
)
 
}
)
```

UI.R :

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny app"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      #Import des tables panel et achat
  fileInput("pan", label = "Import panel table",
            multiple = FALSE,
            buttonLabel = "Browse",
            placeholder = "No file selected",
            accept =  c('.RData')),
  fileInput("achat", label = "Import purchase table",
            multiple = FALSE,
            buttonLabel = "Browse",
            placeholder = "No file selected",
            accept =  c('.RData')),
  
  
    ),

  mainPanel(
  tableOutput('t'),
  tableOutput('t2'),
    )
  )
)
```

any help please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly normal. `Rdata` files may contain multiple objects. The function `load` return the names of the loaded objects, so your `panel` and `achats` reactive will return the names of the stored objects. This is not what you want ! Instead return the object stored in the provided environment. I would also not store that object in the current frame but instead in a new temporary environment (`new.env()`). Expect also a problem if the given `rdata` file contains multiple object !

If you want single object file, you'd better use RDS files. You then could use `p<-readRDS(dataPath)` to load and store it !

```
    ...
    if (!is.null(input$pan)) {
      tmp_env <- new.env()
      p <- load(input$pan$datapath, tmp_env )
      if(length(p)==1)
        p <- tmp_env[[p]]
      else
        p <- NULL # better generate error !
    }
 p
```

Comment: You are welcome. If I answered your question, can you accept it (click on the check mark beside my answer) ?

Comment: I have another question, im using the function paste to print some text in the mainPanel, by using renderText, sometimes i need to go to a newline so i use \n in the paste function, but when i do cat(paste(text)), the text is printed in console not in the app. any idea please ?

Comment: Hello. This is another question not related to the one you asked. Next time you should ask a new question and not continue in the comments. For now look at [Outputting multiple lines of text with renderText() in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233497/outputting-multiple-lines-of-text-with-rendertext-in-r-shiny)